# How to fix script for checking is installed certificate

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have problem with my script. I make script for checking for installed crt certificate in Windows.

```
FOR /F "tokens=* USEBACKQ" %%F IN (`"openssl.exe 2>nul" x509 -in root-public.crt -noout -subject`) DO (
    SET var=%%F
)

rem ECHO %var%

FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3,4 delims=/" %%A IN ("%Var%") DO (
    FOR /F "tokens=1,2 delims==" %%E IN ("%%D") DO (
        SET var=%%F
    )
)

ECHO %var%
```

Show OU from certificate only.
I want get/check certificate from root store system Windows (OU) and comparing this two params.

How i can get/verify certificate from Windows Truested root store?

Detailed info:
I running the proxy with a command line. This Proxy must have installed certificate in browser. I want to create a script before I run Proxy app it to verify if the certificate is already installed in Windows. Or not. If it does not, install it. If it is already installed, the installation skips.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: `"openssl.exe 2>nul"` is a typo, I hope?

Comment: Stephan: no, it is for eliminate errors. I use this batch on Windows as portable and if removed " 2>nul" then show error: "WARNING: can't open config file: /usr/local/ssl/openssl.cnf". I dont using config file.

Comment: Yes. Question is: How i can get/verify certificate from Windows Truested root store?
This published script getting OU param from CRT file on HDD. And i want commands or script for get/verify certificate from Windows Certificeta store from "Trusted Root Certification Authorities". From my last test i know one command for getting (certutil -verifystore -enterprise -v root), and now i working for parsing this. But I do not think this complex solution is right. So I'm trying to ask if y could do better.

Comment: because of the quoting, `"openssl.exe 2>nul"` is treated as a filename (obviously non-existent). You probably meant: `"openssl.exe" 2>nul` instead (although using redirection in the middle of a command is not recommended; use `2>nul command parameter` or `command parameter 2>nul`).

Comment: @truefriend-cz, how about, you provide feedback on my answer, which was intended to fix/improve what you had in your question. Once you've done that, we may get a better idea of what you're looking for, because I get the impression that what you've posted, even when fixed, does not attempt to do the tasks you require of it.

Comment: Compo: What do you want me to do? You have the information in the post. Are the information sufficient?

Comment: @Stephan, in this specific case I believe the strange way of quoting would even work, because the command line is executed within `for /F` by `cmd /c`, which removes them anyway; of course, you are absolutely right, this way of quoting should not be done, as it will cause trouble in almost every situation; this one seems to be one of the rare exceptions...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks all for solutions. Solution is:

```
for /f "tokens=4 delims=/" %%A in ('"OpenSSL.exe x509 -in root-public.crt -noout -subject 2>nul"') do for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ("%%A") do set "varfile=%%B"

for /f "tokens=1" %%A in ('certutil -user -enterprise -v -store root ^| find "OU=handling"') do for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%B in ("%%A") do set "varstore=%%B"

for %%A in ("%varfile%") do for %%B in ("%varstore%") do if "%%~fA" NEQ "%%~fB" (echo Error: Certificate Not exist)
```

Comment: truefriend-cz, I'm sorry to have to bring this up, but do you think it courteous or appropriate to take the code, which solves the specific issue in your question code, and makes up my answer, add some irrelevant lines below it, and then accept your own answer. Please show a little more respect for the time I gave to helping you with your problem, do the right thing and mark my answer as accepted again!

Comment: I must accepted all reactions for this problem of this system stackoverflow restriction for new questions. System has been blocked questions if i not selected any reactions as acceptable. I have no choice but to keep myself at least fairly. I would have to falsely denote answers that did not help me, or I can not ask anyone anymore and i have this feature is blocked. I do not know what to choose. I had to mark all the answers that did not solve my problem as if they helped me and I was completely satisfied, otherwise I could not ask any other question. I have function "ask question" blocked.

Comment: System show message: "You have reached your question limit
Sorry, we are no longer accepting questions from this account. See the Help Center to learn more.". And in help is info why. I must select reactions as solved. Ok, i set all answers as accepted although they are not the solution. Otherwise, I should not ask anybody else to ask or help me with anything. I can only write comments and I will not solve anything. I do not know what to think about. I apologize for declaring your answer to be resolved. It's not a solution.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: ...and i do not set answers as upper or down arrows because i dont have 15 reputations. The limitations that this server has is impossible to meet for new users. I have written to the owners of this server many times, but they are indifferent to that. They do not care.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like one line version of what I think the code in your question is supposed to look like:

```bat
@For /F "Tokens=4 Delims=/" %%A In ('"OpenSSL.exe x509 -in root-public.crt -noout -subject 2>Nul"') Do @For /F "Tokens=2 Delims==" %%B IN ("%%A") Do @Set "Var=%%B"
```

To test it add the following line below it.

```bat
@Set Var & Pause
```

...and let us know what happened.